# why integrating over error function gives nothing?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I try to integrate over an error function and evaluate the following integral

```
Integrate[ 
 Erf[(cep (re + rp) + 2 \[Alpha]2)/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[cep])], {rp, 
  0, \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> 
  re \[Element] Reals && rp \[Element] Reals && cp \[Element] Reals &&
    re > 0]
```

but it gives nothing. why??!

Comment: Try: Integrate[Erf[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]   To see why this doesn't converge, plot it.

Comment: Thanks but it does not give "Integral of Erf[x] does not converge on {0,\[Infinity]}" in my case, it just returns the initial expression!

Comment: Try: `NIntegrate[Erf[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thanks, but I need an analytical answer!

Comment: $\text{erf}(x)\approx 1$ and "does not give not coverage........".Try: `Integrate[1, {x, 0, Infinity}]` ?  Analytical answer is: $$\infty$$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk So how can I obtain an analytical solution for this using Mathematica? However this is a small part of a large integral which I try to solve step by step!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 f = Integrate[Erf[(cep (re + rp) + 2 \[Alpha]2)/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[cep])], rp]
 
  (*(E^(-((cep (re + rp) + 2 \[Alpha]2)^2/(2 cep))) Sqrt[
 2/\[Pi]])/Sqrt[cep] + (re + rp + (2 \[Alpha]2)/cep) Erf[(
 cep (re + rp) + 2 \[Alpha]2)/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[cep])]*)
```

And using  fundamental theorem of calculus:

```
 Limit[f, rp -> Infinity, Assumptions -> {cep > 0, re > 0, \[Alpha]2 > 0}] - 
 Limit[f, rp -> 0, Assumptions -> {cep > 0, re > 0, \[Alpha]2 > 0}]

 (*\[Infinity]*)
```

On **MMA 12.2.0** works fine.

[image]
[image]

To work quit kernel and start again.

Comment: So if I obtain an analytical solution I should change the upper limit to a finite number?

Comment: @Wisdom $\infty$ is infinty number.You can try: `Integrate[
 Erf[(cep (re + rp) + 2 \[Alpha]2)/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[cep])], {rp, 0, INF},
  Assumptions -> {cep > 0, re > 0, \[Alpha]2 > 0, INF > 0}]` where `INF` is a finite number.